# Issue with selectively undoing functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, tkinter, undo

I have created a program in the turtle canvas in which the user can press any letter key on the keyboard and the turtle draws the corresponding letter in the canvas. I have also implemented an undo function that undoes the last function called by clearing the canvas then redrawing everything up until the point before the undone action. This undo function works by the user pressing a tkinter button at the bottom of the canvas labeled "Undo" or pressing the "left" key on the keyboard.

However, I have also decided to create a dynamic (a.k.a. selective, nonlinear, etc.) undo method in which there is a tkinter drop down menu and each drawing function, as it is called, is written to that menu. Then, from the menu, the user can select the function she previously called that he/she wants to undo and the program will undo that specific function instance. The whole process is described below:

The tkinter drop down menu is created through the following code block:

```
# global variables because next code block located ABOVE this one
global fav
fav = Menubutton(text = "Selective redo", state = DISABLED)
fav.pack(side = "left")
fav.menu = Menu(fav, tearoff = 0)
fav["menu"] = fav.menu
global redo1
redo1 = fav.menu
fav.pack()
```

When letter drawn, that letter's point object written to menu using code block below:

```
po = Point(v,y,c,w,isdown(),x,ph,pw)
undo1.add_command(label = Point.__str__(po), command = lambda: selectundo(undo1.index(po)))
# 'po' is a Point object for each function, and the string of that is the label of the menu item
```

`Point.__str__()` is this Point object method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "({})".format(self.function)
```

Finally, user supposed to be able to select –from menu– which instance of letter to undo, and program undoes that letter instance using the user-defined function below:

```
def selectundo(x):
    for ty in range(x, len(function)):
        undoHandler()
        update()
        listen()
```

The issue here is that when the user chooses to draw two or more of the same letters, they both get written to the menu with the same exact index values and thus, if the user wants to undo say, 1 of those, it will instead undo ALL instances of the letter from the canvas, not just the one selected by the user! However, I want the program to ONLY undo the instance of the letter that the user selects from the menu. **Any ideas on how I would fix this issue?** Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: you should add unique number to label as you try in previous question. But you should try harder to find solution - maybe problem was in different place than you expect.

Comment: btw: you can use `str(po)` instead of `Point.__str__(po)` because `str()` will be use `Point.__str__()` automatycally for all `Point` objects.